# django. Templates working local but not on pythonanywhere.com

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

I have a working project in django when I run it local but not when I run it on pythonanywhere.com. I get error TemplateDoesNotExist.

How do I make it run on pythonanywhere.com?

Do i have to do something in the code or in pythonanywhere web app settings?

Thanks!

My code:
settings.py

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

DEBUG = True

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]



DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}



AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]



STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets'),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use the relative directory `'templates'` in your `TEMPLATES` setting. Try changing `DIRS` to:

```
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```