# Django 404 error with TemplateView

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have urls in app and when I go to article-report url I see django error page 
with urls for article, but there is no url for article-report.

main.urls.py

```
from rest_framework import routers
from main.views import (ArticleViewSet)
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'article-report', TemplateView.as_view(template_name = 'report.html'),'report')
router.register(r'article', ArticleViewSet)
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

part of settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

The terminal receives a message

```
[26/Jul/2017 14:22:14] "GET /article-report HTTP/1.1" 404 5777
```

P.S.
Pycharm underlines django,TemplateView and rest_framework in import lines.
But in other examples It doesnt matter

Comment: share your settings file there will be a `TEMPLATES` variable. share the configuration for that.

Comment: I have added an answer for `TEMPLATES` settings. please check it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should include the `TemplateView` as a `url()` in `urlpatterns`, instead of trying to register it with the router.

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'article', ArticleViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'article-report', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='report.html'), name='report')  # note kwarg name='report' instead of arg 'report'
]

urlpatterns += router.urls
```

Answer (score 1):

In your settings.py file, make sure that path to `report.html` is added in `TEMPLATES -> DIRS`.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'quiz.templates')
            # your path instead of this ^
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: 'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'main/templates')]    I added this line but there is no any result

Comment: you also need to solve the routers problem. your code had both issues. @Alasdair has explain how. Check his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your template DIR was empty...

ensure your structure before init `DIR path`

```
my_app->
   my_app
   static
   templates->
      report.html
   manage.py
```

as well use ensure your URL use it like this, **name='report'**

**urls.py**

```
url(r'article_report', TemplateView.as_view(template_name = 'report.html'), name='report')
```

**settings.py**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'your_app.templates')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'debug': DEBUG,
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'production_app.context.bot_context_processor'
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: my_app is inside other app. I tryed to add settings.py for this module and there is no result. Django doesn't know what is name param and I change to base_name and haven't result.

Answer (score -1):

```
.
├── djangooo
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
└── templates
    └── report.html




TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            'templates', # if you use templates folder, you add this.
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: how directory will take base path?

Comment: django knows base path.

Comment: It's not a good idea to use a relative directory `'templates'`. Either hardcode the absolute path, or use `os.path.join()` as in the other examples.

Comment: if you dont add this settings django first looking your appfolder/templates folder. so you create your appfolder into templates or you add this settings to templates DIRS. If you add DIRS settings django looking this folder and yourapp/templates folder.

Comment: @Alasdair I use in production. If templates folder outside our projects you right but this case templates folder in our project folder.

Comment: ` its working.` is not same as best practices. You should edit @HakanYalcinkaya

Comment: It doesn't work in all cases. It might work for you at the moment but it's fragile, and might break when you deploy to another environment. Here's [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45217545/django-templates-working-local-but-not-on-pythonanywhere-com/45217719#45217719) from last week where it caused problems.

Comment: @Alasdair thans for your answer.

Comment: @ArpitSolanki thans for your answer